# What is the maximum inertial g-load of glass?

Tags: optics, material-science, stress-strain, experimental-technology

We are designing a lens system for an experiment that **might** be carried aboard a rocket. For the proof of concept study, we have to present design capable of withstanding 20 to 25 g loads( in lateral and axial directions of our setup). We were wondering whether the glass and quartz lens in our setup be able to withstand such load. Would glass break/crack under such loads?

Answer (score 2):

One cannot answer a question like this with the information given. The answer depends crucially on the shape of the object, its size and on how the object is mounted and therefore how the chassis will transmit force to the object to accelerate it. As an extreme example consider a glass object if many tonnes suspended in the rocket from above by a glass fiber barely thick enough to support its weight. The tiniest acceleration will cause the support to shiver. In contrast, sub millimeter glass beads suspended in oil could withstand thousands of g acceleration without coming anywhere near fracture.

You will need to stimulate the object in detail under acceleration in its proposed chassis with a full FEM analysis to check that the internal stresses do not exceed the strength of the glass. Certainly, a small enough glass object with the right mounting will withstand the accelerations you speak of.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. We intend to perform some simulation in coming weeks. But what I was asking for was a crude first order estimate. I was wondering if there is a way to identity the material response based on specific strength.

Comment: @karthikeyan no, the crucial notion is that the stress should be lies than the strength and it's a great deal more complicated than simply maximum acceleration. Look at the glass bead example versus the large body example to understand that there are many more factors.